# Display Data with Format in Datagridview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Lets say you have a column in Datagridview that has Negative and Positive Numbers that act as a data.

How can you display numbers with negatives into Open and Close Parenthesis?
For example -5.00 will turn to (5.00)

How can I achied that? TYSM

Comment: You mean automagically? You can do a check before adding the row

Comment: What do you mean? I did some mysql command on some fields of my my table there will be a negative output so where do i will adjust? In `Datagidview`,`Update`,`MySQL`?

Comment: I'd try to implement it into the SQL Select statement then. Up 2 you

Comment: I dont know how to do it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default format for that column:

```
DataGridView1.Columns(n).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)"
```

Some further info on formatting can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Comment: It works, but why? Can you explain the meaning of the format string?

Comment: I've added a link to the MSDN doc on this formatting. Sure they'll do a better job explainaing it clearly than I would.

Comment: Sir may i ask? How can i format it with commas and decimal? like this (1,111,111.00)

Comment: I put this code in Datagridview Cell Format but why the datagridview looks blinking?

Answer (score 1):

Answering to your comments.

Doing it in SQL add to your query something like this:

```
SELECT IF(VALUE<0, ABS(VALUE), VALUE)
```

Or

Doing it in vb.net:

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) _
    Handles dataGridView1.CellFormatting

    If dataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name.Equals("YOURCOLUMN") Then
        If CInt(e.Value) < 0 Then
            e.Value = "(" & Math.Abs(e.Value).ToString("N") & ")"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sir may i ask? How can i format it with commas and decimal? like this (1,111,111.00)

Comment: Sir pls help me in my question